# HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error from php mailer form

Tags: php, error-handling, smtp, mailer

I have been working on this for some time, searching forums and I can't seem to find the issue with my code.

I have a request info form with several fields that I am trying to process through PHP Mailer.  When I hit submit it directs me to my process.php page which displays blank in the browser. I am getting this error HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error and do not have access to my server logs to troubleshoot there. If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Thanks!

```
<?php

require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->From = "webmail@averybiomedical.com"; //Sender address 
$mail->FromName = "Information Request "; //The name that you'll see as Sender 
$mail->Host = "remote.averybiomedical.com"; //Your SMTP mail server 
$mail->Port = '587'; 
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; //Protocol to use 
$mail->AddAddress("info@averybiomedical.com"); //The address you are sending mail to 
$mail->Subject = "Mail Subject"; //Subject of the mail 
$mail->Body = $_POST["title"] . "   " .
$_POST["firstName"] .  "   " .
$_POST["lastName"] . "   " .
$_POST["degree"] . "\n" .
$_POST["address1"] . "\n" .
$_POST["address2"] .  "\n" .
$_POST["address3"] . "   " .
$_POST["city"] . "   " .
$_POST["state"] . "   " .
$_POST["zipCode"] . "   " .
$_POST["country"] . "\n" .
$_POST["email"] . "   " .
$_POST["email2"] . "\n" .
$_POST["phone1"] . "   " .
$_POST["phone1_location"] . "   " .
$_POST["phone2"] . "   " .
$_POST['phone2_location'] . "   " .
$_POST["phone3"] . "\n" .
$_POST["relation"] . "   " .
$_POST["relation_specif"] . "\n" .
$_POST["physician_specialty"] . "\n" .
$_POST["surgeon_specialty"] . "\n" .
$_POST["prof_specify"] . "\n>" .
$_POST["other_specify"] . "\n" .
$_POST['diagnosis']. "\n" .
$_POST['Insurance']. "\n" .
$_POST["funding"] . "\n" .
$_POST["source"] . "\n" .
$_POST["comments"] ; //Body of the message 
$mail->SMTPAuth = "true"; 
$mail->Username = "myemail@averybiomedical.com"; //valid email id of the domain 
$mail->Password = "mypassword"; //password for abc@xyz 

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else { 
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

Comment: did you really name a file `class.phpmailer.php` or is that supposed to be a backslash?...

Comment: yes that is the name of the file and it is placed in the same directory as the process.php

Comment: The form can be tested at http://d13627715.k169.newworldhosts.com/requestInfo.html if anyone wants to see if they can find the real error.

Comment: Also the syntax checks out, loading the code into zend studio and it didn't throw a tantrum. ALSO turn on error reporting for that page.

Comment: Added error_reporting(E_ALL); to my php but still getting blank page with original server error

Comment: just a thought, have you tried point it to a different file name other than process.php, also, have you tried just `print_r()`? if you have and the issue persists then the problem will be with the server or file name and not the code

Comment: Well the last thing I suggest is to start with a blank page, and add one line at a time until the page breaks. Sometimes this is the only way.....

Comment: when you use from https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/ you also need to copy the other files. With only class.phpmailer.php in your directory it won't work. PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'class.smtp.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/bass/Dropbox/testomgeving/testdrive/class.phpmailer.php on line 968